# How to create a sql constraint for new or updated record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to automatically insert create date time in a column for every new row and update time when that row is updated in updated time column. I know it can be done using sql constraint.

And I have done for create date:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
  ADD CONSTRAINT CO_Persons_AutoCreateDate DEFAULT GetDate() for CreatedDate
```

But how do you do that for updating record in updated date?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_somename
ON Persons
FOR UPDATE
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE T
  SET T.createddate = GETDATE()
  FROM persons T INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON t.pk_column = I.pk_column

END
```

Comment: I strongly believe in using capitals for key words but I'm using my phone to answer this post so sorry about the poor formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

In `INSERT` statement use all columns except `CO_Persons_AutoCreateDate`.

For example if you have table `Persons` like this:

```
Create Table Persons
(
A int,
B int,
CO_Persons_AutoCreateDate datetime
)
```

use `INSERT` statement:

```
insert into Persons (A,B) values (1,1)
```